# how to run a dbt container from command line with volumes

Tags: docker, dbt, volumes

was trying to make a quick dbt container:

`docker pull xemuliam/dbt`

```
docker run -d --name dbt \
-p 8085:8085 \
-v /home/mypath/app:/usr/app \
xemuliam/dbt:latest
```

that didn't work, so i tried to inspect and saw the binding was rprivate, so i changed it to:

```
docker run -d --name dbt \
-p 8085:8085 \
-v /home/mypath/app:/usr/app,rshared:rshared \
xemuliam/dbt:latest
```

the issue is that /home/mypath/app ends up being empty, and if i go inside the container it has in the working directory of /usr/app:

```
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root  4096 Apr 29 12:24 .
drwxr-xr-x  1 root root  4096 Jun 21 20:14 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root  4895 Apr 28 16:54 ARCHITECTURE.md
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root root 16732 Apr 28 16:54 CHANGELOG.md
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root 18081 Apr 28 16:54 CONTRIBUTING.md
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root  2239 Apr 28 16:54 Dockerfile.test
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root 11344 Apr 28 16:54 License.md
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root  3271 Apr 28 16:54 Makefile
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root  2365 Apr 28 16:54 README.md
drwxrwxr-x  5 root root  4096 Apr 28 16:54 core
drwxrwxr-x  4 root root  4096 Apr 29 12:23 dbt-core-1.1.0
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root   205 Apr 28 16:54 dev-requirements.txt
drwxrwxr-x  2 root root  4096 Apr 28 16:54 docker
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root   777 Apr 28 16:54 docker-compose.yml
drwxrwxr-x  3 root root  4096 Apr 28 16:54 docs
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root    51 Apr 28 16:54 editable-requirements.txt
drwxrwxr-x  2 root root  4096 Apr 28 16:54 etc
drwxrwxr-x  3 root root  4096 Apr 28 16:54 events
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root    65 Apr 28 16:54 mypy.ini
drwxrwxr-x  8 root root  4096 Apr 28 16:54 performance
drwxrwxr-x  6 root root  4096 Apr 28 16:54 plugins
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    95 Apr 29 12:23 plugins.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root   242 Apr 28 16:54 pytest.ini
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root    26 Apr 28 16:54 requirements.txt
drwxrwxr-x  2 root root  4096 Apr 28 16:54 scripts
drwxrwxr-x  5 root root  4096 Apr 28 16:54 test
drwxrwxr-x  7 root root  4096 Apr 28 16:54 tests
drwxrwxr-x 10 root root  4096 Apr 28 16:54 third-party-stubs
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root   798 Apr 28 16:54 tox.ini
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Apr 29 12:24 wheels
```

in my postgres db i am able to do a volume like this and it works:

`-v /home/mypath/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data`

i would like to access that stuff on the host so i can play around with editing it.

Comment: You might need to add rw permissions e.g. `/home/mypath/app:/usr/app:rw`

Comment: @fritz tried that too

Comment: Usually the mount-propagation options (`rshared`, `rprivate`) don't matter to you.  What is in `/home/mypath/app` on the host before you start?

Comment: @DavidMaze absolutely nothing, i just made it so i can interact with the container...

Comment: Then the bind mount will replace `/usr/app` inside the container with the empty host directory, which may not be what you want.  Can you restructure the application so that you interact with it using, say, HTTP requests, instead of sharing files?

Comment: @DavidMaze that's exactly what's happening.  but it doesn't happen when i do it with postgres - postgres populates the host directory with the files that are in the container.  i am trying to just spin up the most basic instance of this app - which is pretty popular called dbt.  the image i posted is the official one so not sure how i would restructure without dockerfile...

Comment: The `postgres` image has an entrypoint script that creates a new empty database in the data directory if there isn't anything there already.  It doesn't copy anything from the image.

Comment: @DavidMaze ok i did not know that, so i guess alot of these images like nginx do the same thing.  would it be ok to post the official dockerfile to see if there is a way to add volumes?

Comment: For the `nginx` image, the base image contains a default `index.html` file that you usually don't want to show, so hiding it with mounted (or `COPY`ed) content is fine.  What sort of changes are you proposing to make to this image?  Do you have your own Dockerfile `FROM xemuliam/dbt`, perhaps?

Comment: @DavidMaze my goal is to just be able to access the ```/usr/app``` folder on the host side - so that i can configure whatever i want from the host.  i've never used dbt before and so i figured this would be a great opportunity to test out containerization

Comment: @DavidMaze this is the official:``` https://github.com/xemuliam/docker-dbt/blob/main/Dockerfile```

Comment: @DavidMaze ive also tried setting up a volume in a different directory inside the container and then creating a symlink to /usr/app, but i quickly learned that this just shares a symlink on the host which links to a nonexistent folder on that host

Answer (score 0):

this is probably the worst way to get this done, so i would appreciate a better answer - but my solution:

```
step 1: pull image
    $   podman pull xemuliam/dbt
    
step 2: create a container through cli instead of dockerfile
    $   podman run -d --name db_dbt \
        -p 8085:8085 \
        -v /home/myusr/dbt_test/_official:/home/dbt_test/_official \
        xemuliam/dbt:latest
    
step 3: copy files from /usr/app to /home/dbt_test/_official
    $   cp -R /usr/app/* /home/dbt_test/_official
        exit
    $   podman stop db_dbt && podman rm db_dbt
    
step 4: copy files on the host
    $   mkdir /home/myusr/dbt_test/app1
    $   cp -R /home/myusr/dbt_test/_official/* /home/myusr/dbt_test/app1/
    
step 5: create a new volume
    $   podman run -d --name db_dbt \
        -p 8085:8085 \
        -v /home/myusr/dbt_test/app1/:/usr/app/ \
        xemuliam/dbt:latest
```

i really dont like this roundabout way, but now i am able to edit from the host and see what the container does.